# Using MLMultiArray as input of an mlmodel in Xcode

Tags: swift, coreml, mlmodel

I'm struggling to implement my model in Xcode using CoreML tools.

The implemented model looks like this :

[mlmodel in xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7W7R.png)

The code of the viewController looks like this :

```
let model=blackjack()
let mlMultiArray = try? MLMultiArray (shape:[13,1,1],dataType : MLMultiArrayDataType.double)        
for (index,element) in vecteurCarte.enumerated() {
    print(type(of: element))
    mlMultiArray![index] = NSNumber(floatLiteral: element)
    }
    
let i = blackjackInput(cardPlayed: mlMultiArray!)
let prediction = try? model.prediction(input : i)
print("prediction label: ")
print(prediction?.classLabel ?? "No prediction possible")
print("probability per label :")
print(prediction?.output ?? "No prediction possible")
```

The error I get using this is :
[coreml] Failure verifying inputs.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help

Alex

Comment: We need code, not images of code

Comment: What if you use shape `[13]` instead of `[13, 1, 1]`?

Comment: I have this error when trying [13] instead of [13,1,1]:
[espresso] [Espresso::handle_ex_] exception=Unsupported engine type